# Spring + Hibernate connection pooling connection not happening

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, persistence

I am trying to implement connection pooling in my Hibernate/Spring webservice, the config is as follows.

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${dataSource.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${dataSource.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${dataSource.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${dataSource.password}"/>
<!--
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="5000"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="100"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
-->
</bean>
<!--ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc)--> 

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.limousine.domain.AddressDetails</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>-->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

But I am getting not getting connected exception.

Comment: any concrete log file?

Comment: The config looks fine (but as Ralph mentioned, please provide a lof file). And a word of caution: if this is intended for a production system you might want to change [maxWait](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) to something lower, and fail fast. Otherwise you might get a resource starvation with your connections

Comment: exception = (org.hibernate.HibernateException) org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here.... this is the exception i am getting now

Comment: put a more complete stack trace in your question.  btw, such kind of problem normally happened in lazy fetching happened outside txn.  This is usually caused by inapprorpriate txn boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You are using different versions of hibernate for creating Session Factory (hibernate4) and Transaction Manager (hibernate3). Make them use the same hibernate versions.

Use

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager
```

and

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

Comment: Thanks Sandhu for your reply, actually i was tweaking around to get this worked, n ended up in this config which i pasted here. But i am  using both hibernate3 now.